# localStorage after JSON.parse gives null _id in vue state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

Currently playing with vue and vuex.  I have a state which would get item from localStorage.
I cannot figure out why after `JSON.parse` the item from localStorage in state, somehow everything is fine except for `_id` it'll be null

this is how my state and getters looks like

```
const BROCHURES = 'brochures';

const state = {
  brochures: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(BROCHURES)) || []
};

const getters = {
  show_brochures: (state, getters, rootState) => {
      console.log(state.brochures)   // this will give me _id: null, but other fields are good
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(BROCHURES))  // this would return everything fine
  }
};
```

sample item in `getItem(BROCHURES)`

```
[{ "has_feature_sheet": false, "images": [ "efsdf.png", "asdf.png" ], "instructions": [ { "sort": "1", "page": "1", "isImage": false, "textarea": "131111" } ], "isDeleted": false, "_id": "5f8e0765b041c24e230b36d2", "size": 2, "folds": 2, "price": 111, "createdAt": "2020-10-19T21:38:45.935Z", "updatedAt": "2020-10-19T21:38:45.935Z", "__v": 0 }]
```

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

EDIT:
This is where I use the `getters`

```
<template lang="html">
  <sui-grid celled>
    {{ show_brochures }}
  </sui-grid>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'FillBrochure',
  computed: mapGetters(['show_brochures']),
};
</script>
```

Comment: difference between `BROCHURES` and `'brochure'`? How many keys are stored in localStorage?

Comment: In this line brochures: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(BROCHURES)) || [], are you sure that BROCHURES is equal to 'brochure' string

Comment: @RandyCasburn my bad, I was using constant as BROCHURES, let me edit the post, my bad on the typo here

Comment: @lissettdm yes, sryz for my typo in this post, I re-edited

Comment: it used be be 'brochure' in the first post, now its 'brochures` :: how many keys are stored in localStorage?

Comment: And when you call getters.show_brochures method, how are you passing the state arg?

Comment: @RandyCasburn there are other keys such as `select_size` but nothing close to `brochures`, it's my bad on typo here when posting

Comment: @lissettdm I am not calling `getters.show_brochures` anywhere at this moment though, does that matter?

Comment: @Dora, yes, you get _id: null, inside that function, I suppose that you call it at some point,  and the state inside the function is different form the state outside

Comment: @lissettdm I editted where I use it

Comment: What does the `get_brochure` getter look like? How does any data make its way into `localStorage`?

Comment: @Dora I Think the problem is underscore '_' in that prop. Here you can find the answer https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and API methods.
Taken from : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

Comment: sounds reasonable for the explanation, just when using mongodb it'll be `_id` so did not think of that causing it